# How To Use The Simplex Method When Having More Variables Than Constraints

Tags: linear-programming, simplex

I have been learning the Simplex Method for solving minimization and maximization problems, but came across a small problem with every resource I have found online.

They all seem to imply that excluding my non-negativity constraint, I should have the same number of variables as constraints. For example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8_D3gkrgeK8

Now let's say I had a problem with 20 variables and 7 constraints. For example:
$$C=a_1X_1+a_2X_2 +...+a_{20}X_{20}$$
$$b_1X_1 + b_2X_2 +...+b_{20}X_{20} \ge q_1$$
$$c_1X_1 + c_2X_2 +...+c_{20}X_{20} \ge q_2$$
$$d_1X_1 + d_2X_2 +...+d_{20}X_{20} \ge q_3$$
$$e_1X_1 + e_2X_2 +...+e_{20}X_{20} \ge q_4$$
$$f_1X_1 + f_2X_2 +...+f_{20}X_{20} \ge q_5$$
$$g_1X_1 + g_2X_2 +...+g_{20}X_{20} \ge q_6$$
$$h_1X_1 + h_2X_2 +...+h_{20}X_{20} \ge q_7$$
$$X_1, X_2, ..., X_{20} \ge 0$$

To my understanding, per the dual method, I put these equations into a matrix, take its transpose, and rewrite my equations then. That would give me 20 equations with 8 variables. So then when I introduce my slack variables (which will be my original X1 X2 etc), I should only have 19, which is one less than the amount of variables I had. Am I to choose one to ignore somehow? Or have I made a mistake in my logic somewhere.

Any help would be deeply appreciated, thank you.

Comment: $\texttt{"I should only have 19, ..."}$ Why do you think that?

Comment: Well if I have 20 equations, one would be my primary function that I'm trying to maximize, and the other 19 would be my constraints, and slack variables to my understanding were only added to constraints to turn them into equalities.

Comment: The objective (primary) function of the dual is formed based on the RHS of the primal: $\sum\limits_{m=1}^7 q_m\cdot y_m$. And the constraints of the dual are formed based on the $X_i \ \forall \ i\in \{1,2,\ldots, 20\}$

Comment: @callculus Apologies for the delayed response. Thank you very much for the help! I'm not sure how I managed to get that mixed up, but this helped me clear it up. I'm still fairly new to this site, is there any way I can acknowledge your help if it's comment form?

Comment: No, problem. A delayed response is $10^{10}$ times better than no response. There is not really an option to acknoledge my effort. The only thing you can do is to upvote one or some of my comments. But a nice comment like a above is enough for me.